# How long does a Ubuntu shutdown script have during a shutdown?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have a script setup in `/etc/rc6.d/` and `/etc/rc0.d/` to be executed when the machine goes down.  However, there seems to be a strict time limit for how long those scripts can run. (This makes sense, otherwise a buggy shutdown script could completely prevent a machine from rebooting.)

Q) How long is that time limit? Is there a config file somewhere that shows it?

Q) Can I increase this time limit?

If it helps, my "uname -a":
Linux 3.2.0-60-virtual #91-Ubuntu SMP

Comment: Look into /etc/init.d/sendsigs, method do_stop()

Answer (score 1):

There is no time limit for a specific init script.  If you wanted to use `alarm` or something you could create a time limit of your own, but the system does not impose one for you.

The script Nils mentions runs after most of the other init scripts are completed.  The timeouts in there do not apply to other init scripts.